# A calculator with customizable buttons

Tags: windows, calculator

I already use the Windows 10 app Calculator that comes preinstalled, and the scientific mode works fine for what I need it for, for the most part.

What I need is a Windows program that has all the functionality of the above, as well as the ability to add extra buttons for calculations that I do frequently. Simple stuff like 1-x, and if possible, slightly more advanced use of storage variables for time conversion, etc.

In terms of UI I'm thinking either a drag and drop type of thing or a set of unused buttons that can be labeled and given functions of my own.

The closest programs I've found to what I need are:

[Precise Calculator](http://preccalc.sourceforge.net/)

Which has "macros" that seem to just amount to pasting in a set of characters, with no possibility of directly affecting what I've already typed.

[CustomCalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visacsoft.customcalcfree&hl=en_US)

An android app that has drag and drop buttons but you can only choose from a collection of possible functions, with no ability to add your own.

I've also heard of making a calculator from scratch using Python, which while not entirely out of the question, it would require me to learn a new programming language. I've already programmed a few things, but not in Python. A slightly better solution would be if there is an open source calculator of this kind that can be built upon.

Comment: i only know [`galculator`](http://galculator.mnim.org/) which can [do this easily](http://galculator.mnim.org/documentation.html#userdefined), but it is a *nix-program... but anyway [cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) is mentioned at the homepage and maybe you can built upon [its source](https://github.com/galculator/galculator) since it is FOSS under GPL2.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy galculator doesn't seem to install, even in cygwin, however there is the possibility I'm doing something wrong, after all, I downloaded cygwin for this purpose so I'm not exactly a master. The homepage for it has a lot of broken links, including the one that mentions cygwin.

Comment: i'm neither a master at cygwin and have no Windows at the moment for testing/helping, but [according to its site](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgalculator%2Fgalculator-2.1.4-1&grep=galculator) it should install and work. - maybe the [FAQs](https://cygwin.com/faq.html) and the [user guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net.html) is worth a look.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I managed to install it as a package from the cygwin setup file (I was doing something different before), but I get an error message anytime I try to run it:
"Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

(galculator:11996): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

I get the feeling I need to install another package but I don't know what.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get around the error message, and opened galculator. The function ability is the closest to what I want from what I've seen, however from what I can tell I would need to open cygwin, type in a few commands, and then I would be able to open it, and only one instance. This is less convenient than I need out of a calculator. Does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: you have to start a [x-server](https://x.cygwin.com/), which should/[can be automatized](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html). **||** only one possible instance must be a regression by cygwin i don't know...

Comment: as you talked about writing a calculator yourself, maybe you can port and build upon it since [it is written in C](https://github.com/galculator/galculator).